# Одинаковые объекты в списке

Tags: c#

Вот метод в котором создаются несколько объектов по алгоритму.

В консоль они печатаются разными. (Это начинается отсюда)`Console.Write(" -" + bufer[i] + "- ");`

Но когда дело идёт до отображения списка - то они все равны последнему элементу. (Это начинается отсюда)`foreach(var item in URO)`

У меня есть проект, где я поступаю таким же образом. Там все объекты разные, а тут они одинаковые, хотя каждй раз создаётся новый объект.

```
private static void Strike()//составление матрицы из цены опоры и повреждённых фрагментов
        {
            List<Uroboros> URO = new List<Uroboros>();
            int[] bufer = new int[15];
            double summ = 0;
            double[,] matrix = new double[2, 15];

            string[] ls = InputCost.Split(' ');
            for (int i = 0; i < ls.Length; i++)
            {
                matrix[1, i] = double.Parse(ls[i]);//занесение всех стоимостей в массиц матрикс для удобства
                matrix[0, i] = i;
            }

            Boolean a = true;
            Boolean b = true;
            Boolean p = true;
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int jbl = 0;
            while (a)//основное тело цикла
            {
                summ = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < bufer.Length; i++)
                {
                    bufer[i]=0;
                }

                while (b)//генерить пока не будет удовлетворять условию
                {
                    int value = rnd.Next(0, 12);
                    for (int j=0; j<bufer.Length;j++)
                    {
                        if (value == j) { bufer[j]=1; bufer[0] = 1; bufer[14] = 1; }
                    }
                    for(int i=0; i< bufer.Length-1; i++)
                    {
                        if (bufer[i] != 0 && bufer[i + 1] != 1 || bufer[i] != 1 && bufer[i + 1] != 0 || bufer[i] == 1 && bufer[i + 1] == 1)
                        { /*Console.WriteLine("-1 "+(i+1)+"\n\n");*/ if (i + 1 == 11) { /*Console.WriteLine("------------2" + "\n\n");*/ b = false; } }
                        else
                        { /*Console.WriteLine("---3" + "\n\n");*/ break; }
                    }
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < bufer.Length; i++)
                {
                    Console.Write(" -" + bufer[i] + "- ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();

                for (int i=0; i<bufer.Length;i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < bufer.Length; j++)
                    {
                        if (bufer[i] == matrix[0, j]) { summ += matrix[1, j]; }
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine(summ);

                //Uroboros c = new Uroboros(summ, bufer);
                URO.Add(new Uroboros(summ, bufer)); //новый объект

                if (jbl++ == 3) { a = false; }
                b = true;

            }

            foreach(var item in URO)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
            }

            //return 0; 
        }
```

Вот класс по которому создаются объекты.

```
class Uroboros
    {
        public double fSumm { get; set; }
        public int[] fmsv { get; set; }
        public Uroboros(double i1, int[] i2)
        {
            fSumm = i1;
            fmsv = i2;
        }
        public override string ToString()//переопределние метода ТуСтринг для более красивого вывода результата
        {
            string s1 = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < fmsv.Length; i++)
            {
                s1 += Convert.ToString(fmsv[i]) + " ";
            }
            s1 = s1 +" "+ fSumm;
            return "\n"+s1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Объекты всё-таки разные...

Summ всегда разная.

А вот массив int[] bufer в объекта равен последнему.

Comment: Ваш код напоминает шифровки написанные в спешке в тылу врага. Почему нельзя дать нормальные имена переменным и свойствам, а нужно писать такое `fSumm` `fmsv` `double i1, int[] i2` `URO` пальцы болят что-ли? Вы утверждаете что `Одинаковые объекты в списке` в чем эта одинаковость выражается? Как проверяли? Отладкой занимались?

Answer (score 0):

Инициализацию массива надо перенести 
`int[] bufer = new int[15];`
К `summ = 0;`